# How can a user1 blocks user2 from sending messages to user1. - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where users can chat with each other. One to one. I want to give users the ability to block a particular users list from sending him messages.

A code example would be appreciated.

Comment: why not have a blocked list of every user on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming user 1 is trying to send message to user2.
You can use below snippet to run before sending the message.

I assume you have a `users` node in your firebase database containing all users in the database.

Logic: user 1 is trying to send message to user 2. If user 1 is present in block list of user 2, do not allow to send.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference()
            .child("users")
            .child("id_of_user2") 
            .child("block-list") // fetching block-list of user2
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    List<String> blockList = dataSnapshot.getValue(List.class);
                    if (blockList.contains(id_of_user1)){
                        // block list of user2 contains id of user1, 
                        // DO NOT ALLOW TO SEND MESSAGE
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```